# Exporting a random sample from CSV file to a new CSV file - output is messy

Tags: python, csv, pandas, random

I am trying to export a random subset of a CSV file to a new CSV file using the following code:

```
with open("DepressionEffexor.csv", "r") as effexor:
    lines = [line for line in effexor]
    random_choice = random.sample(lines, 229)

with open("effexorSample.csv", "w") as sample:
   sample.write("\n".join(random_choice))
```

But the problem is that the output CSV file is very messy. for example, some part of a data in a filed was printed in the next line. How can I solve the problem? In addition, I want to know how can I use pandas for this problem rather than CSV. Thanks !

Comment: have you looked at [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html#pandas.DataFrame.sample)?

Comment: How about that : `shuf -n 229 DepressionEffexor.csv > effexorSample.csv`

Comment: @Loïc: apart from (like the OP's code) not handling the header if there is one, if there are LFs within elements that will fail, and the OP's description makes it seem like there might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you had a CSV read into pandas:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("csvfile.csv")
sample = df.sample(n)
sample.to_csv("sample.csv")
```

You could make it even shorter:

```
df.sample(n).to_csv("csvfile.csv")
```

The [Pandas IO docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-store-in-csv) have a great deal more information and options available, as does the `dataframe.sample` method.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas, this translates to:

```
import pandas as pd

#Read the csv file and store it as a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('DepressionEffexor.csv')

#Shuffle the dataframe and store it
df_shuffled = df.iloc[np.random.permutation(len(df))]

#You can reset the index with the following
df_shuffled.reset_index(drop=True)
```

You can splice the dataframe later to choose what you want.